# How much time do I have if I want to sue a county for sending me to prison accidentally California U.S.A

Tags: california, sentencing, prison

I was sentenced to 16 months county time non violent offender but my paperwork was supposedly lost and ended up with the prison commits and I was sent to prison. Two weeks before my release date my counselor told me that my county was sending 2 sheriffs to pick me up because I wasn't supposed to be there. I was on a level 4 yard with murderers and lifers.

Comment: What is county time?

Comment: You should definitely pursue this to the fullest extent.

Answer (score 1):

You have one year, given [Civ. Proc. 340(c)](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=CCP&sectionNum=340). However, that time might have started when you were first sent to prison, insofar as there are three standards for computing time-elapsed (date of harm – being sent to the wrong place), date when you reasonably should have discovered the harm, and date when you actually discovered the harm. There is no provision to the effect that the clock doesn't start until you know that the harm is legally actionable. Of course, you should talk to an attorney.

Comment: ... so it's too late to sue the state/county for wrongful imprisonment if you wait until you're not in prison???

Comment: Probably, but ask your attorney because there may be an obscurity attached to your case that tolls the statute of limitations.